# Updating team drive permissions with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, service-accounts

We are experiencing an issue updating team drive permissions via a service account.

We have demonstrated the ability to list drives and drive permissions with a service account. However, when we try to update a permission (following code snippet) we encounter an error:

```
service.permissions().update(fileId=id, permissionId=permissionid, supportsTeamDrives='true', body={"role": "reader"}).execute()

"The authenticated user does not have the required access to update the permission."
```

We've ensured the service account has the manager role assigned for the team drive. We've also validated that we are able to update permissions from internal and external accounts that have the manager role.

Is this an intended limitation for service accounts? Is this a bug?

Updates in comments.

Comment: To work around this I have explicitly authorized the service-account ("api-client") for our Gsuite with an overly broad scope. I've also set useDomainAdminAccess=true without success. This did not work.

I will next try to impersonate a Gsuite user from the service-account as a possible workaround.

Comment: Impersonating one of the original Gsuite user accounts that was able to modify the team drive permissions manually did not work. I receive the following error:

`"The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."`

Very perplexing as the user does in fact have permission to update that permission, as i demonstrated.

Comment: Also tried impersonating a super admin account that also has manager access to the team drive. I receive the same error.

Comment: I just discovered that one can use the `create` method to update permissions by changing the role. So I guess this is a bug or I am grossly misunderstanding the purpose of `update` versus `create` for permissions.